# How to calculate z- value of absolute value or modulus for normal distribution. i.e: $P(|X-a|>b)$

Tags: normal-distribution

Lets say $X\sim N(3,9)$ where variance= 9. What is $ P(|X-3|>6)$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Sorry, for some reason its not letting me post the rest of my question in the detail box, im only able to post this much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to solve $|X-3|>6$.

i) For $X-3>0$ we have

$X-3>6\Rightarrow X>9$

ii) For $X-3<0$ we have

$-X+3>6\Rightarrow X<-3$

---

Thus $P(|X-3|>6)=1-P(-3<X<9)=1-\left(\Phi\left(\frac{9-3}{3} \right)-\Phi\left(\frac{-3-3}{3}\right)\right)$

$=1-\left(\Phi(2)-\Phi(-2)\right)=1-\left(2\Phi(2)-1 \right)$

$=2-2\Phi(2)$

Comment: Cheers!  :-)))))

Comment: @RandyRogers You´re welcome